# Outlook programmatically avoid Attachment.SaveAsFile() Pop-up on XSL

Tags: vb6, outlook

I have developed a Outlook polling service that does the following:

The service is not a windows service but a rich client.

It is developed in Visual Basic 6.

1. The "robot" basicly polls outlook for new mails
2. If a new mail is found the Attachment.SaveAsFile(path) is used to save each attachment.
3. When I save Excel files (xls) extension. Outlook will launch Excel and Excel will pop-up with the following message with older xsl files (prior excel 2000).
      "Do you want to save the changes to 'SaveAttFromBlaBla.xsl'?
      "Microsoft Office Excel recalculates formulas when opening files last saved by an earlier version of Excel."

Does anyone know of a way to not have the pop-up occur? And by default select "Yes" to recalculate?

Thanks

Comment: I found there is a VB6 property that does just that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175241%28office.11%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Works with Word as well.